# Rails: grouped_collection_select with select2 search doesn't return associated options

Tags: jquery, ruby, activerecord, jquery-select2, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm using Rails 6. I'm using a grouped_collection_select for the following associations:

```
class Client
  has_many :matters
end

class Matter
  belongs_to :client
end
```

My select code looks like the following:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:matter_id, Client.joins(:matters).group('clients.id'), :matters, :name_with_code, :id, :name_with_code, {include_blank: 'Select a bank account'}, {id: 'one_drive_matter_select', :style => "width:100%"}) %>
```

My jquery:

```
$("#one_drive_matter_select").select2({
    theme: "material",
    placeholder: I18n.t('select_matter'),
    allowClear: true
 });
```

Looks something like this:
[image]

The user can have the freedom to search for either a client or a matter. However, when I search for the client the respective matters seem to disappear to select.
I want to show the associated matters to be shown when I search for a client. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably closer to something you want

```
options = Client.all.map do |client|
 [client.name, client.matters.map do |matter|
   [matter.name_with_code, matter.id]]
end

<%= f.grouped_options_for_select(options) %>
```

Comment: I believe the grouped_options_for_select does not belong to the formbuilder. 
I get an undefined method 'grouped_options_for_select' error.
And even if I pass it in the second parameter, it does reflect the matters on search.